# Animate borders in Angular 2 / Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to animate the borders around a profile pic, so it looks like the borders are getting bigger and than smaller, as though the image was radiating like a radio signal / wave. But the animation does not appear to take effect...

[image]

**CSS**

```
   .Pic {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: rgba(215, 255, 255, 0.3);;
      position: relative;
      border: 25px solid rgba(215, 255, 255, 0.3);;  
      margin: 4px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 1.1em 
    }
    .Pic:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: -15px;
      left: -15px;
      right: -15px;
      bottom: -15px;
      background: #ddd;
      z-index: -1;
      padding: 1.1em
    }
```

**ANGULAR**

```
animations: [
  trigger('pictrigger', [
    state('inactive', style({
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
    })),
    state('active',   style({
      backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
      transform: 'scale(1.1)'
    })),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
```

**HTML**

```
< img src="pic1.jpg" [@pictrigger]  >
```

Comment: Could this not be done solely in css by just applying a class?

Does the border appear at all?

Comment: I need to animate it, I am not sure how to do it in CSS either...